# Installing of Adobe Air file fails with "file damaged"

Tags: air

Adobe Air brings following exception:

> The application could not be installed because the AIR file is
>   damaged. Try obtaining a new AIR file from the application author.

Please add the different reasons which may lead to this error.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same error [as this guy](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/444007):

The file ~/.airappinstall contains the following error:

> failed while unpackaging: [ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false
>   cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="invalid package signature"
>   errorID=5022]

The actual reason was not a damaged file or something like this, but our machine had a date from the past, which was not valid for the given certificate. After correcting the date/time on the computer, the installation worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the same `error=5022`, after thinking a lot on this issue, I finally got the 
solution for this problem. It is simple, before installing the air app set the correct Date & Time for the system, WALLA it installs smoothly.

No need of changing the png name or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem yesterday because my antivirus (avast pro/silent mode) was blocking access to file until finishing scanning, looks like installer don't like to wait, so when I switched off silent mode I made antivirus ignore scanning the file and installation completed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I have a virtual drive mapped to S: so that paths are the same between my home computer and work computer. I was trying to install the AIR app from an S: path. I guess it did it like it. Moving app to my desktop and launching there, worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are signing the Application distributable and distributing the certificate along with the .air file.

I ran into same problems and solved it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when using Flash Builder 4, but building a Flex 3 application.

Basically, the installed AIR SDK in the Flex 3 SDK folder was AIR 1.5.3 (if I remember correctly), but the Flex 4 SDK folder had the AIR 2.0 SDK files (I'm not completely what the problem was).

My solution was to download the AIR 2.0 SDK, and unzip it over the Flex 3 SDK folder. Once I did that, the installation file worked fine. There is actually an article on Adobe about overwriting the AIR SDK files this way, although it didn't mention anything about installations or Flash Builder 4.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was failing because I had another app on my system with the same name. Not a version of the app, a completely different app--native, not AIR.

Once I removed that app it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For odd installation errors, keep in mind that Chrome uses a version of Flash that does not support AIR badge installation.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when trying to install an AIR file from an external / network drive. Copied the file locally, and installation proceeded normally.